# Can Power BI custom visuals accept keyboard focus?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am trying to create a custom slicer that supports keyboard navigation.

I have come across the `supportsKeyboardFocus` property in capabilities.json, and I see that this changes the `visual` HTML element to look like the built in slicer which does support keyboard navigation (removes `aria-hidden="true"` and adds `keyboard-shortcuts="ctrl-ArrowRight scoped"`) but am still unable to get keyboard focus inside a simple custom visual. Are there any working examples of a custom visual that supports keyboard navigation?

Answer (score 0):

There was a regression in custom visuals' keyboard focus support, it has been fixed a few months ago.

In order to enable keyboard focus and navigation, the visual should:

1. Set `supportsKeyboardFocus: true` in capabilities.json file.
2. Contain focusable elements<sup>1</sup>

Also note that in a Power BI report, visuals behave as context groups, so navigation *between* visuals is achieved using `Tab`, and navigation *into* a visual's context is done by `ctrl`+`rightArrow` (or `cmd`+`rightArrow` for Apple).

---

<sup>1</sup>: While there are many DOM elements which are focusable by default (e.g. buttons, text input etc.), many custom visuals are based purely on SVG graphics, so they can end up with no focusable elements. For the most basic tab based navigation, adding `tabindex=0` to an element is enough. For good accessibility, depending on the visual, it's typically required to add keyboard support for selection and multi-selection, and better navigation (e.g. arrow based grid navigation, or some reasonable grouping of elements etc.)